# Spring and WildFly Infinispan cache lookup

Tags: java, spring, jboss, wildfly, infinispan

I have implemented caching in my Spring application and when I run it locally everything works fine. I have `infinispan.xml` configuration in resources and the following configuration:

```
spring.cache.type=infinispan
spring.cache.infinispan.config=classpath:infinispan.xml
```

Now I would like to deploy it to WildFly 10 and to use built in cache. I have defined my cache container with `jndi-name=infinispan/CONTAINER`.

I tried setting `spring.cache.infinispan.config` to:

```
infinispan/CONTAINER
java:/infinispan/CONTAINER
java:jboss/infinispan/CONTAINER
```

But I allways get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cache configuration does not exist
```

What should I do make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible at the moment.

You will need to extend [SpringEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/8.2.x/spring/spring4/spring4-embedded/src/main/java/org/infinispan/spring/provider/SpringEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean.java) and override `#createBackingEmbeddedCacheManager()` method. Then use `JndiTemplate` to grab a reference to `EmbeddedCacheManager` deployed in WildFly (similarly to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584215/infinispan-with-spring-casting-from-cache-failing)).

I also created [ISPN-7208](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-7208) to allow specifying JNDI references for Cache Managers.